# How to create template with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

i have tree project like this:

```
root/ 
nameFolder/ template.php
foo/ ....
bar/ ....
..........
```

how can i load `template.php` when i go on
`https://mywebsite.com/nameFolder/38`  (or `https://mywebsite.com/nameFolder/(number)`)?

I don't t have physically the folder 38 (or any number) `https://example.com/nameFolder/38` i only have `https://example.com/nameFolder/template.php`. I just want load the same page for every `/folder/(number)`

I can't figure out with `.htaccess`

(like Wordpress do)

Comment: Check out the answer by @MrWhite, let them know if it worked.

Comment: You've not stated whether you need to pass the `(number)` to your `template.php` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give any specific requirements, but the following in `/folder/.htaccess` would "load `template.php` when you go to `https://example.com/folder/38`".

Specifically, it rewrites the URL from `/folder/38` to `/folder/template.php` using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^38$ template.php [L]
```

> **UPDATE#1:** or `https://mywebsite.com/folder/(number)`

Then change the above to read:

```
RewriteRule ^\d+$ template.php [L]
```

`\d` is a shorthand character class that represents `[0-9]` (ie. the digits 0 to 9).

> **UPDATE#2:** I don't t have physically the folder `https://example.com/folder/38` i only have `https://example.com/folder/template.php`

It's a bit misleading using the term "folder" if "folder" does not actually exist as a filesystem *folder* (subdirectory). If it doesn't physically exist on the filesystem, then what you have here is just a "URL path segment" - a virtual URL path. (*EDIT: Although later edits appear to suggest that it's just the "38" that is not a physical subdirectory.*)

In this case, create a `.htaccess` file in the document root and change the above directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/\d+$ folder/template.php [L]
```

---

**UPDATE#3:** You've not stated whether you need to reference the `(number)` in your `template.php` file? If you do then you can either parse this from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable in your PHP script (this probably gives you most flexibility, and is how WordPress does it), or you can explicitly pass this as a URL parameter as part of the URL rewrite.

For example, to pass the *number* as the `id` URL parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(\d+)$ folder/template.php?id=$1 [L]
```

`$1` is a backreference to the first captured group (ie. `(\d+)`) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. the *number*).

This *number* is then available in your PHP script using the `$_GET['id']` variable.

Comment: Change it to a wildcard.

Comment: :D That works out now. Lets wait for the OP to reply. I was about to answer it with the same. But LOL you already did, so there's no need for me to answer, you have more explanations.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address "folder" as a virtual URL path segment.

Comment: I've updated my answer to suggest how you might access the _number_ in `template.php` if required.

Comment: The answer 2 works very good. The third one remind me to error 404. Thanks you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. The "third one" should work as well (in the _root_ `.htaccess` file) - but you would need to remove the `/folder/.htaccess` file first.